# insert multiple values from sub query to column of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert value from my sub query

my query is like that..

```
insert into T_Scanned(F_Asset_Code) values (select F_Barcode from T_Assets where F_Barcode
in(  select Barcode as barcoade  from  [T_NEWASSET]))
```

but this is not working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `VALUES` when doing an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
insert into T_Scanned(F_Asset_Code) 
select F_Barcode from T_Assets where F_Barcode
in(  select Barcode as barcoade  from  [T_NEWASSET])
```

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, thanks for the explanation. (I was just writing the same thing, but slightly slower.)

Comment: No...you blew me out of the water here, this is why I didn't bother to finish writing :-)